# Validating array - get current iteration

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-validation

I'm trying to validate a POST request using Laravel's `FormRequest`.

The customer is submitting an order, which has an array of items. We are requiring the user to indicate whether the item needs `special_delivery` only if the `asking_price > 500` and the `quantity > 10`.

The following are my intended rules:

```
public function rules() {
    'customer_id' => 'required|integer|exists:customers,id',
    'items' => 'required|array',
    'items.*.name' => 'required|string',
    'items.*.asking_price' => 'required|numeric',
    'items.*.quantity' => 'required|numeric',
    'items.*.special_delivery' // required if price > 500 && quantity > 10
}
```

I've attempted to do something along these lines:

```
Rule::requiredIf($this->input('item.*.asking_price') > 500 && $this->input('item.*.quantity' > 10));
```

The problem with this is that I can't find a way to access the current `items` iteration index to indicate which item to validate against.

I also tried the following custom validation:

```
function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {

    preg_match('/\d+/', $attribute, $m);

    $askingPrice = $this->input('items')[$m[0]]['asking_price'];
    $quantity= $this->input('items')[$m[0]]['quantity'];

    if ($askingPrice > 500 && $quantity > 10) {
        $fail("$attribute is required");
    }
}
```

Although this function gives me access to the current `$attribute`,the problem is that it will only run if `special_delivery` exists. Which defeats the entire purpose!

Any help will be much appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might've come up with a solution to your problem, a index aware `sometimes` if you so will.

Since it's unfortunately not possible to add macros to the Validator, you would either have to override the validation factory (that's what I suggest) and use your own custom validation class or make a helper function based off the method, pass the Validator instance as an additional parameter and use this instead of `$this`.

## Sauce first: the `indexAwareSometimes` validation function

```php
function indexAwareSometimes(
    \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator $validator,
    string $parent,
    $attribute,
    $rules,
    \Closure $callback
) {
    foreach (Arr::get($validator->getData(), $parent) as $index => $item) {
        if ($callback($validator->getData(), $index)) {
            foreach ((array) $attribute as $key) {
                $path = $parent.'.'.$index.'.'.$key;
                $validator->addRules([$path => $rules]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A lot of inspiration obviously came from the [`sometimes` method](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html#method_sometimes) and not much has changed. We're basically iterating through the array (the `$parent` array, in your case `items`) containing all our other arrays (`items.*`) with actual data to validate and adding the `$rules` (`required`) to `$attribute` (`special_delivery`) in the current index if `$callback` evaluates to true.

The callback closure requires two parameters, first being the form `$data` of your parent validation instance, retrieved by `Validator::getData()`, second the `$index` the outer `foreach` was at the time it called the callback.

In your case the usage of the function would look a little like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class YourFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'customer_id'          => 'required|integer|exists:customers,id',
            'items'                => 'required|array',
            'items.*.name'         => 'required|string',
            'items.*.asking_price' => 'required|numeric',
            'items.*.quantity'     => 'required|numeric',
        ];
    }

    public function getValidatorInstance()
    {
        $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();

        indexAwareSometimes(
            $validator, 
            'items',
            'special_delivery',
            'required',
            fn ($data, $index) => Arr::get($data, 'items.'.$index.'.asking_price') > 500 &&
                Arr::get($data, 'items.'.$index.'.quantity') > 10
        );
    }
}
```

## Extending the native `Validator` class

Extending Laravel's native [Validator class](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html) isn't as hard as it sounds. We're creating a custom ValidationServiceProvider and inherit Laravel's `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider` as a parent. Only the `registerValidationFactory` method needs to be replaced by a copy of it where we specify our custom Validator resolver that should be used by the factory instead:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Validation\CustomValidator;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\Translator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Factory;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider as ParentValidationServiceProvider;

class ValidationServiceProvider extends ParentValidationServiceProvider
{
    protected function registerValidationFactory(): void
    {
        $this->app->singleton('validator', function ($app) {
            $validator = new Factory($app['translator'], $app);

            $resolver = function (
                Translator $translator,
                array $data,
                array $rules,
                array $messages = [],
                array $customAttributes = []
            ) {
                return new CustomValidator($translator, $data, $rules, $messages, $customAttributes);
            };

            $validator->resolver($resolver);

            if (isset($app['db'], $app['validation.presence'])) {
                $validator->setPresenceVerifier($app['validation.presence']);
            }

            return $validator;
        });
    }
}
```

The custom validator inherits Laravel's `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` and adds the `indexAwareSometimes` method:

```
<?php

namespace App\Validation;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class CustomValidator extends Validator
{
    /**
     * @param  string  $parent
     * @param string|array $attribute
     * @param string|array $rules
     * @param Closure $callback
     */
    public function indexAwareSometimes(string $parent, $attribute, $rules, Closure $callback)
    {
        foreach (Arr::get($this->data, $parent) as $index => $item) {
            if ($callback($this->data, $index)) {
                foreach ((array) $attribute as $key) {
                    $path = $parent.'.'.$index.'.'.$key;
                    $this->addRules([$path => $rules]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then we just need to replace Laravel's `Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider` with your own custom service provider in `config/app.php` and you're good to go.

It even works with [Barry vd. Heuvel's `laravel-ide-helper` package](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper).

```
return [
    'providers' => [
        //Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
    ]
]
```

Going back to the example above, you only need to change the `getValidatorInstance()` method of your form request:

```
public function getValidatorInstance()
{
    $validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();

    $validator->indexAwareSometimes(
        'items',
        'special_delivery',
        'required',
        fn ($data, $index) => Arr::get($data, 'items.'.$index.'.asking_price') > 500 &&
            Arr::get($data, 'items.'.$index.'.quantity') > 10
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can call `$validator = parent::getValidatorInstance();`  since the parent returns out of the function, the `indexAwareSometimes` will not be called. You can rewrite the entire function, but I consider that too risky and generally try to stay away from doing that.
I did find that you can call the `indexAwareSometimes` inside of the  `withValidator` function that accepts `Illuminate\Validation\Validator` as a param. This automatically gets called and no need to override anything else.

Comment: You can use the result of a parent method, I tested it. Glad it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [closure](https://laravel%20validation%20in%20requird_if%20callback%20get%20attribute).

```
'my_array.*.value' => [
        'required',
        function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                $currentArray = $this->input(Str::beforeLast($attribute,'.')));
                /* any validation logic */
        },
]
```